# Not able to get a desktop kind of a window

Tags: electron.net

On windows, when I run the **electron.net app** see a **desktop-style window**. However, on a Mac, I see that **the same app is being shown in a browser**.

```
        var browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions
        {
            Width = 1000,
            Height = 600,
            Show = false
        });

        browserWindow.OnReadyToShow += () => browserWindow.Show();
        browserWindow.SetTitle("Electron.NET API Demos");
```

How could I avoid giving the browser feel for a electron.net app on a Mac?

It's an **asp.net core 3** based app using **electron.net**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Mac, I updated the **electron-builder package** using npm and it works.